# CakePHP v2.10.20 Console "Mysql" is missing ... "Selected driver is not enabled"

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-2.x

I just migrated a legacy application to a new server and had to update to php 7.4 and thus CakePHP 2.10 as we re-write the application in CakePHP 4.x.  The application is working just fine and connections to the database are made without issue.  The problem comes in when trying to migrate the shell applications for our CRON jobs.  For some reason they are unable to connect to the database.

Code:

```
class HelloShell extends AppShell {
public $uses = array('Release');

public function main() {
    $user = $this->Release->find('first');
    $this->out(print_r($user,true));
}
```

}

Result:

> Welcome to CakePHP v2.10.20 Console App : app Path:
>   /var/www/vhosts/xxxxxxx.com/cake/cakephp/app/
>
> **Error: Database connection "Mysql" is missing, or could not be created:
>       Selected driver is not enabled**
>
> /var/www/vhosts/xxxxxxx.com/cake/cakephp/lib/Cake/Model/ConnectionManager.php(105):
>   DboSource->__construct(Array) 1
>   /var/www/vhosts/xxxxxxx.com/cake/cakephp/lib/Cake/Model/Model.php(3659):
>   ConnectionManager::getDataSource('dcs') 2
>   /var/www/vhosts/xxxxxxx.com/cake/cakephp/lib/Cake/Model/Model.php(1162):
>   Model->setDataSource('dcs') 3
>   /var/www/vhosts/xxxxxxx.com/cake/cakephp/lib/Cake/Model/Model.php(3686):
>   Model->setSource('releases') 4
>   /var/www/vhosts/xxxxxxx.com/cake/cakephp/lib/Cake/Model/Model.php(3053):
>   Model->getDataSource() 5
>   /var/www/vhosts/xxxxxxx.com/cake/cakephp/lib/Cake/Model/Model.php(3025):
>   Model->_readDataSource('first', Array) 6
>   /var/www/vhosts/xxxxxxx.com/cake/cakephp/app/Console/Command/HelloShell.php(8):
>   Model->find('first') 7
>   /var/www/vhosts/xxxxxxx.com/cake/cakephp/lib/Cake/Console/Shell.php(459):
>   HelloShell->main() 8
>   /var/www/vhosts/xxxxxxx.com/cake/cakephp/lib/Cake/Console/ShellDispatcher.php(222):
>   Shell->runCommand('main', Array) 9
>   /var/www/vhosts/xxxxxxx.com/cake/cakephp/lib/Cake/Console/ShellDispatcher.php(66):
>   ShellDispatcher->dispatch() 10
>   /var/www/vhosts/xxxxxxx.com/cake/cakephp/app/Console/cake.php(47):
>   ShellDispatcher::run(Array) 11 {main}

I have verified that the following configurations have been added to the php.ini:

> Extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll Extension=php_mysql.dll

I have spent hours reading similar issues, but none match up.  ANY HELP is greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: `mysql_*` API was removed in PHP 7.

Comment: Check whether the version of PHP (and installed modules) that you're getting on the command line matches the version that you're getting through your web server.

Comment: @Greg Schmidt  I used debug(phpversion());  from both my shell application and my web application, and they **ARE** different.  My web application is showing. version 7.4.5. while the shell is showing 7.2.24.  I don't actually understand this.  Should I update the system php version to 7.4.5?  How does this create the issue I am having (I am baffled).

Comment: @Greg Schmidt THANK YOU! THANK YOU!  You set me on the right path.  I got it working by installing the newest release **AND** installing the most common modules.